Is there a service provided by the OS, which is NOT accessible by the terminal emulator?
Is there a service provided by the OS, which is NOT accessible by the terminal emulator? If so, how else would the user be accessing it?
(My guess is, there wouldn't be since that would be silly. But I'm only an undergrad in CS and probably am missing something.)

Our site works differently than others you might be used to (e.g., Quora).  The title should be used for a short summary of what to expect in the post, not a full sentence or full copy of the question (and the body of the post should stand on its own).  We have collected some advice here on how to write a title.

Thank you for that @D.W.

OS services can be invoked by system calls, which can be invoked by programs running on the machine.
The terminal emulator is a way that a human can interact with a command-line shell or other program.  Anything you type into the terminal emulator will be passed on to the shell or whatever other program is running.  So you cannot directly invoke any OS service from a terminal emulator; but you might be able to send the shell a command that, when executed, runs a program that invokes OS services.

So just to confirm, are you saying that to access any services that OS provides, it must be done via the shell ?

@Lucky, No, I'm not saying that.  Any program can invoke system calls (and thereby invoke the OS).  A shell is a program that is designed to enable humans to execute other programs.  Normally most of our command-line interaction with computers is done by interacting with a shell, which then starts other programs, and those other programs make system calls.
